# Composite C1 v4.2 Available Packages is Empty

Tags: orckestra-cms

I am **new** in Composite C1. I Strictly want to use C1 V4.2 and Add a add-on in it. 
When I try to add any add-on, everywhere under installation guide they say :=> Go to the "System" perspective. > Open the folders “Packages” | “Available Packages” | " Composite.Tools".

But problem with it is I am not able to see anything under **“Available Packages”**.

Anybody knows why is this problem?

Guys please do not ask to upgrade CMS C1 to any new version, because task (assignment) given to me is to add any add-on in CMS C1 V4.2 only.

Can anybody help me add any Add-on in CMS C1 V4.2 or any guide link to do it.

FYI I am trying to add "Composite.Tools.SqlServerDataProvider" add-on for now.

Refer the screenshot here [CMS Available packages empty](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cie4N.jpg)

Any help is appreciated.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Refer : https://github.com/Orckestra/CMS-Packages/issues/62

**InnaBoitsun** has answred this as below and it worked.

When C1 CMS v. 5.0 was released, most of packages was updated to support new C1 CMS v. 5.0 UI, so they require minimum C1 version = 5.0, so you don't see any packages in Available Packages.
For the Composite.Tools.SqlServerDataProvider packahe you can review package history here https://github.com/Orckestra/CMS-Packages/commits/master/Composite.Tools.SqlServerDataProvider and see when minimum version was changes, and download the package for the previous version.

Try to download previous version by that link https://github.com/Orckestra/CMS-Packages/raw/13b9e4c5ea026207a787031f764f90f920d1e719/Composite.Tools.SqlServerDataProvider/Composite.Tools.SqlServerDataProvider/Release/Composite.Tools.SqlServerDataProvider.zip
and install package as local package.